# Synchronize NiFi process groups or flows that don't/can't connect?

Tags: apache-nifi

Like the question states, is there some way to synchronize NiFi process groups or pipelines that don't/can't connect in the UI?

Eg. I have a process where I want to `getFTP->putHDFS->moveHDFS` (which ends up actually being `getFTP->putHDFS->listHDFS->moveHDFS`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50166151/8236733). However, `listHDFS` does not seem to take any incoming connections. Trying to do something with process groups like `P1{getFTP->putHDFS->outport}->P2{inport->listHDFS->moveHDFS}` also runs into the same problem (`listHDFS` can't seem to take any incoming connections). We don't want to `moveHDFS` before we ever even get anything from `getFTP`, but given the above, I don't see how these actions can be synchronized to occur in the right order.

New to NiFi, but I imagine this is a common use case and there must be some NiFi-ish way of doing this that I am missing. Advice in this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what requirement is preventing you from writing the file retrieved from FTP directly to the desired HDFS location, or if this is a "write *n* files to HDFS with a `.` starting the filename and then rename all when some certain threshold is reached" scenario.

`ListHDFS` does not take any incoming relationships because it should not be triggered by an incoming event, but rather on a timer/CRON schedule. Every time it runs, it will produce *n* flowfiles, where each references an HDFS file that has been detected to be written to the filesystem since the last execution. To do this, the processor stores local state.

Your flow segments do not need to be connected in this case. You'll have "flow segment A" which performs the FTP -> HDFS writing (`GetFTP -> PutHDFS`) and you'll have an independent "flow segment B" which lists the HDFS directory, reads the file descriptors (but not the content of the file unless you use `FetchHDFS` as well) and moves them (`ListHDFS -> MoveHDFS`). The `ListHDFS` processor will run constantly, but if it does not detect any new files during a run, it will simply yield and perform a no-op. Once the `PutHDFS` processor completes the task of writing a file to the HDFS file system, on the next `ListHDFS` execution, it will detect that file and generate a flowfile describing it.

You can tune the scheduling to your liking, but in general this is a very common pattern in NiFi flows.